# Trying to find all combinations of a 2-state vector (in python)

Tags: python, list, combinations

I am trying to find all combinations of a four element vector that contains only 1's and -1's.
Ex (1,1,1,1),(-1,1,1,1),...(-1,-1,-1,-1) etc
My idea to do this is pretty inefficient im sure but I can't think of another way to do it, so here is what I was trying to do.
I found how many total vectors there would be, then created that many empty lists. I began with vector `A` and then compared this to each list in `vectors`. If `A` matched any of the lists then I randomly changed the sign of an element of `A`, and then again checked the new list `A` against `vectors`. If `A` didn't find a match then it replaced on of the lists in `vectors`, and the while loop was incremented by 1. This should proceed until all possible combinations have been found and printed.
However my code is just spitting out the first change in `vectors` then continually looping without adding any new `A`'s to `vectors`. Can anyone spot what in my code isn't doing what I intended it to do and/or point me in the right direction? Thanks

```
import random
numvec = 2**4 # number of macrostates for a 4 component 2-state system

vectors = [[0,0,0,0] for i in range(numvec)] #initializing the numvec vectors 
A = [1,1,1,1]
i = 0
while i < 16:
    if any(x == A for x in vectors):
        y = random.randrange(0, 3)
        A[y] = A[y] * -1
    else:
        vectors[i] = A
        print vectors[i] 
        i += 1

print vectors
```

Oh and again I realize this method is incredibly inefficient but as this is a homework assignment I am more concerned with being able to get python to do what I want it to do, then using a bunch of built in functions to do the work for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vectors[i] = A
```

This doesn't create a copy of `A`. When you change `A`, the contents of `vectors` change, because `vectors[0]` and `A` are the same object after the first time this line runs. To fix this, make a new `A` object every time, or copy `A` and insert the copy into the list.

If you want to make a copy, you can use [Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1427124):

```
vectors[i] = A[:]
```

Comment: yes! that was it! that was the only issue and now it works. thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do this easily with the [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) built-in function:

```
list(itertools.product([-1,1], repeat=4))
```

Alternatively, you could write it all out with a list comprehension. This is much more verbose, but it avoids using the `itertools` library:

```
list((i,j,k,l) for i in (-1,1) for j in (-1,1) for k in (-1,1) for l in (-1,1))
```

Comment: yeah I had gotten that impression that I could use `itertools` but I was trying not to use it as that would be too easy. the point of the assignment was to get some experience using if statments

Comment: ok thanks, that's good food for thought, I will defiantly be looking at what `itertools` can do for future projects

Comment: The second answer doesn't use itertools in case you haven't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

For educational purposes (considering that people with a similar problem are probably looking for the general recursive approach - a classic task)

```
def get_possibilities(elements, length=1):
    if length == 0:
        return [[]]

    if length > 0:
        tails = get_possibilities(elements, length=length-1)
        return [[x] + t for x in elements for t in tails]   

results = get_possibilities([1,-1], 4)
```

How this works by example:

```
[1,-1], length=4
call get_possibilities([1,-1],4) (main)
call get_possibilities([1,-1],3) (from get_possibilities)
call get_possibilities([1,-1],2) (from get_possibilities)
call get_possibilities([1,-1],1) (from get_possibilities)
call get_possibilities([1,-1],0) (from get_possibilities)

return [[]] (from the [1,-1], 0 call)

merge any element (here 1,-1, as list) with any element of the prior return
return [[1],[-1]] (from the [1,-1], 1 call)

merge any element (here 1,-1, as list) with the prior return
return [[1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, 1], [-1, -1]] (from the [1,-1], 2 call)

merge any element (here 1,-1, as list) with the prior return
return [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, -1], [1, -1, 1]...] (8 elements, 2**3) (from the [1,-1], 3 call)

merge any element (here 1,-1, as list) with the prior return
return [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, -1], ...] (16 elements 2**4) (from the [1,-1], 4 call)
```

greetings

PS: i would guess that itertools.product works similarly ;)